# Pipes with while loops within Parentheses

Tags: bash, redirect, while-loop, pipe

I am going to ask about a structure about **pipes with while loops within parentheses**.

Imagine I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

<FirstCommand> | (while read var1; do out=`echo $var1 | <command>` \
                  <sth with $out> done; awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}' OtherFile |  awk 'NF==3{print}{}' | awk '{gsub (/<blank>/,""); print}' > file.txt \
                  while read var2 var3 var4; do <sth> done < file.txt)
```

The point is my script is working correctly till end of first **while** loop. but the second one has a problem.

My question:

Is the output of my `FirstCommand` redirecting to both while loops simultaneously?

About `FirstCommand`:

This is a command that generates some texts and I want to redirect the output of that to while loops run time.

**UPDATE**

The output of  is appending to `OtheFile` that `awk` is using.

Thank you

Comment: Where is awk getting input?  awk will never see any of the text produced by FirstCommand, but will immediately terminate when it tries to read its stdin, because the first while loop has consumed all of the data.

Comment: I put the awk command @William Pursell

Comment: Are you trying to have the second while loop first read the output of the awk, and then the output of FirstCommand?

Comment: I want the output of <FirstCommand> be seen to awk while FirstCommand is running , then while awk is generating output to file.txt the `while loop` do stuff

Comment: So you want the output of FirstCommand to go to the first while loop and to awk, and the output of awk to go to the second while loop?  Then: `firstcommand | while ...; do ... done & firstcommand | awk | while ... do; ... done`.  If firstcommand is expensive, run it first and store its output in a file.

Comment: @William Pursell Thank you but I think this would not be good idea if I run firstcommand two times... How do you see difley's answer?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the first command is being sent to the input of the shell which contains the two loops.  The first loop consumes all of the data.  The input of the second loop is the file file.txt ( the output of the `awk`.  Unless there is some reason not shown here, you might as well pipe the awk directly to the second while loop.)

Comment: Ok, thank you... how can I change this structure and tell to <FirstCommand> that redirect your out put to both while loops simultaneously? And if I sent output of awk to the second while loop the problem disappeared?

Comment: If William is correct, then you might consider using the `tee` command to write the output of FirstCommand to some temp file, then `cat` the temp file into the second while loop.

Comment: @difley Could you possibly show me what you mean with changing the script? thank you

Comment: Do you want each line written by FirstCommand to be seen be both loops?  Are the loops to be run simultaneously, or one after the other?

Comment: I want loops run simultaneously and yes. I want the output of FirstCommand to be seen be both loops. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
<FirstCommand> | tee FirstCommand.output | (while read var1; do out=`echo $var1 |<command>` <sth with $out> done; awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}' $NmapOut | awk 'NF==3{print}{}' | awk '{gsub (/<blank>/,""); print}' > file.txt; cat FirstCommand.output | while read var2; do <sth> done < file.txt)
```

where `FirstCommand.output` is a temporary file that will contain the output of `<FirstCommand>`.

Comment: Thank you is the syntax ``echo $var1 |<command> \ `` correct?

Comment: Nope. The slash should not be present. Removed from the code.

Comment: Note that `OtherFile` is eacltly output of `<FirstCommand>`. So I think you should change it like:<FirstCommand> | (while read var1; do out=`echo $var1 |<command>` <sth with $out> done; awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}' OtherFile | awk 'NF==3{print}{}' | awk '{gsub (/<blank>/,""); print}' > file.txt; cat OtherFile | while read var2; do <sth> done < file.txt) .  Right?

Comment: While I am running my script the `file.txt` isn't created sometimes(I mean when it takes long time I think.)...So do you think `cat OtherFile` would help?

Comment: If you can't get my suggestion to work, you might try William's comment on his answer where he suggested writing the output of `<FirstCommand>` to a temp file and separately `cat`ing the file to the two while loops. I am not sure why `file.txt` isn't created every time.